# Loading Resources in cocos2dx which works both android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I've created folder inside Resources folder called "menu_images" in which my game menu images are stored.
My Problem:
I have to create CCSprite object in two different way in iPhone and android.
In iPhone, I can pass file name by just "menu_item.png" in create() function.
But in Android, I have to pass "menu_images/menu_item.png" in create() function. Which doesn't works in iPhone.

I want to use same code in both platform. Somebody please help me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using `Cocos2d-x-2.2` then take a look at FileUtils in TestCpp demo project.

Comment: It seems it has different folder structure than other sample projects. The Classes folder is being created in TestCpp/ and TestCpp/pro.ios so little confused with this. Have you tried and built TestCpp and android and ios?

Comment: No folder structure is same. it might be issue with X-Code and depend upon how you are adding resources. So you can resolve these issues by setting different different search paths to your CCFileUtils object and then get the absolute path of respective image file and provide it to CCSprite.

Comment: The problem is, I can add multiple search path and make working. But I have to do it in two different way for android and ios, as I explained above.

Comment: I don't think its problem with iOS, You are just adding resources in different way. You can run `TestCpp` and check it is same for all platforms.

Comment: Thanks anyway! Will try to build and see TestCpp project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue by adding items inside resources as references only.Below is the screenshot.[image]

Comment: I've used build_native.sh script to build apk for android, which copies all the resources from Resources/ folder into proj.android/assets folder, That't why it works in android.

Answer (score 3):

Just set search path for the all sub-folders inside Resources in your AppDelegate. You can refer below sample code.

```
CCFileUtils *fileUtils = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils();
std::vector<std::string> searchPaths = fileUtils->getSearchPaths(); 
searchPaths.insert(searchPaths.begin(), "menu_images");
fileUtils->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```

After setting search path you can load any sprite or file like:

```
CCSprite* background = CCSprite::create("menu_item.png")
```

Comment: what if I have two folders Folder1/ and Folder2/ and within both of these folders there is image.png. How can I load Folder1/image.png and Folder2/image.png into two CCSprites?

Comment: searchPaths is a vector that cocos2d-x will iterate through, so something like: searchPaths.push_back("Folder1");  searchPaths.push_back("Folder2");